# Navigate to next screen after logged in

Tags: react-native, react-redux, redux-thunk

i am new to react-native and redux. This is such a simple problem yet I dunno how to solve it. I have successfully logged on but then the screen is not navigated to the next screen. It stays on the login screen. I suspect error comes from my login screen and login action file. I debug the code using Expo XDE and I can see that the login is successful however the page remains on login page. Below is how I want to navigate the screen from the Login screen:

```
 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  console.log('hello',nextProps);
    if(nextProps.isLoginSuccess){
        this.props.navigation.navigate('welcome');
    }
}
```

Below is my login_action file:

```
export const attemptLogin=(username, password)=> async dispatch=>{

let param={
    txtNomatrik: username,
    txtPwd: password,
    public_key: helper.PUBLIC_KEY,
    secret_key: helper.SECRET_KEY

}

console.log(`${helper.ROOT_API_URL}/v1/basic/ad/std/login`)
let login_res = await 
axios.post(`${helper.ROOT_API_URL}/v1/basic/ad/std/login`, param)

console.log(login_res.data);
if(login_res.data.status=='Successful Login'){
   const {login}=login_res.data;
   await AsyncStorage.seItem('Login_token', username);
   await AsyncStorage.setItem('profile',JSON.stringify(login));
   dispatch({type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload:{isLoginSuccess:true}});
}
}
```

Please help me, I wanna proceed to the next step.

This is how I wrote my navigation in app.js

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
render() {

const MainNavigator= StackNavigator({
  login: { screen : LoginScreen,
           navigationOptions:{ header: null},
  logged:{
          screen:  TabNavigator({
                   welcome: { screen: WelcomeScreen },
                   main: { screen : MainScreen }},{
                   tabBarPosition : 'bottom'
             })
  }
}
})
```

Or is there anything wrong with my reducer?:

```
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
   isLoginSuccess: false
}
export default function (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
switch (action.type) {
  case LOGIN_SUCCESS:
   return action.payload
  default:
   return state;
 }
}
```

Comment: Show us your react-navigation navigator config with the route names and what not!

Comment: @WilomGfx  I added my navigator file

Comment: I am so stuck with this problem..help me pls

Answer (score 0):

Replace `this.props.navigation.navigate('welcome');` to `this.props.navigation.navigate('logged');` as your key to another screen is `logged`. `welcome` is key for `TabNavigator`, it has nothing to do with `StackNavigator`.

Comment: nothing changes, the screen still remains on login screen..what should i do?

Comment: ok, this is the link to my code https://snack.expo.io/ryoLAi3-G , sorry i am a total newbie to this

Comment: do you think you can help me with that code i shared?

Comment: I tied running your project, but getting error. I have refactored snack code to make it runnable on sack. https://snack.expo.io/r17OsbRZz. Can you please make is runnable to snack.

Comment: I am getting `Device: (32:164) (0, _reduxPersist.autoRehydrate) is not a function. (In '(0, _reduxPersist.autoRehydrate)()', '(0, _reduxPersist.autoRehydrate)' is undefined)
 imported from app.js`. Are you also getting this error?

Comment: hmmm, it's working fine with me. anyway did you notice any error based on my code? Btw, thank you so much for effort in helping me. I appreciate it :)

Comment: Code seems to be correct, not able to find any error. I have to debug it, which is not possible until, it runs on my side :) Thanks!

Comment: I tried to see the log for nextProps, but it didn't not come out. I think the error comes from the isLoginSuccess not recognized. Do you have any idea why?